# Word for encoder-decoder

Tags: abbreviations

*Modem* is a common word for modulator/demodulator. Is there a word that in a similar fashion (or in general) would describe the encoder and decoder functionality presented in one piece?

Comment: I disagree with the NARQ close vote, as this question *has* been reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: Over-enthusiasm! or maybe, there's a better word for it.

Comment: What about general reference?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A [codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec) or [endec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endec) encodes and decodes.