# A word that describes both "encoding" and "decoding"?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I am looking for a word that describes *both* of these activities, however the word *coding* does not seem to be suitable.

Likewise with *encryption* and *decryption*, *cryption* does not work well.

Comment: It's worth noting that, for practical purposes, a person who encodes/decodes digital information is often professionally called an _archivist_ and refers to his work as _archival_.

Comment: Related: [Word for encoder-decoder](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55545/word-for-encoder-decoder)

Comment: Where would we be without you, @Reg? (knee-deep in unclosed duplicates, I suspect! :)

Comment: I agree this duplicates the related question (which asks for one "word [for] encoder and decoder functionality").  Note, the answer there correctly identifies a device that does both but doesn't answer the question asked.  Should merge questions?

Comment: This question is looking for a verb, the other for a noun. So they are different. There is not really a verb for "codec" or "endec", or none has been proposed so far. And no, the verb "to code" has its own meaning and is not the verb form of "codec".

Comment: Also interesting would be serialize + deserialize.

Comment: @donquixote I've seen SerDe used recently.

Comment: I used Denc as a class name for decryption a encryption, just because I haven't seen a better alternative anywhere.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Cryptography

is the study of encryption and decryption.

> codec

is software/hardware that does both encoding and decoding.

Comment: Cryptography is the study of passing information without a third party being able to receive it.  It wouldn't apply to encoding/decoding mp3s, for example.

Comment: Codec is defined as the library describing the way to encode and decode a format.  This answer is wrong.  Cryptography doesn't relate to the ACTION of encrypting or decrypting, so the extra info you added is also wrong.

Comment: @NathanC.Tresch This answer accepted as codec is the word i was looking for. Debate about crypography TBC.

Answer (score 10):

```
Encode means : "To translate information into code"
Decode means : "To translate code into information"
```

Therefore translate would be used to describe them both.

Since translate may seem vague I would suggest some synonyms:
transcribe, transpose, or convert.

Answer (score 7):

Would *transcoding* be suitable in your context ?

Comment: Unfortunately the parallel construction of "transcryption" just looks like a misspelling of "transcription", which means something quite different. :/

Comment: Ooh. I like transcryption. I shall find somewhere to use that and then shower disdain on those who attempt to correct it.

Comment: "encode" and "decode" mean to translate between a logical form and a storable / serialized / encrypted form of information. "transcode" means to translate between two different encoded forms of information. A transcoder usually decodes and then encodes again, in a different format. A "codec", on the other hand, translates between a decoded and an encoded format, in both directions. So it is not quite the same.

Answer (score 2):

How about pure and simple “processing”?

Answer (score -1):

Why does everyone and OP have a problem with "coding".   This is the correct term for encoding and decoding.   For example, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_theory

Comment: Possibly because in a programming context it can cover almost everything we do. It becomes generic to the point of uselessness.

Comment: @NWS:  The coding of a channel vs. the process of coding a program is not likely to be confused from context.   The subjects aren't even of the same type (abstract idea vs. person)

Comment: In software development, it is desirable for a name to convey most of its meaning *without* much context, since we often work with portions of source code without examining the *full* context.